# How can I diff 2 SQLite files?

Tags: sqlite, ide, diff

Using SQLite-manager (in its XUL form) on a Mac.

How can I diff a SQLite file from one submitted by someone else on the team, and incorporate his changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe you could use the following, in combination:

```
$ diff sqlite-file-1.sql sqlite-file-2.sql > sqlite-patch.diff
$ patch -p0 sqlite-file-1.sql sqlite-patch.diff
```

I hope that works for you. Otherwise, I highly suggest consulting the man-pages:

```
$ man diff
$ man patch
```

EDIT: Alright, here's the whole walk-through.

First, dump the databases:

```
$ sqlite test1.sql .dump > test1.sql.txt
$ sqlite test2.sql .dump > test2.sql.txt
```

Next, generate a diff file:

```
$ diff -u test1.sql.txt test2.sql.txt > patch-0.1.diff
```

And, finally, to apply the patch:

```
$ patch -p0 test1.sql.txt patch-0.1.diff
```

Comment: Doesn't work, as SQLite is a binary file, the only result you get is "binary files differ"

Comment: Won't this break if you modify the schema that already has data in it? For instance if you add a field and want to patch the additional field to an existing database.

Comment: User may need sqlite3 instead of sqlite.

Answer (score 16):

We can use the sqldiff Utility Program:

https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html

It will compare the source to the destination databases and generate SQL commands to make source equivalent to destination.

> - Any differences in the content of paired rows are output as UPDATEs.
> - Rows in the **source** database that could not be paired are output as
>     DELETEs.
> - Rows in the **destination** database that could not be paired are
>     output as INSERTs.

<s>We have to download the sources and compile it, from the tool folder.</s>

Comment: No need to compile, it's available as a precompiled binary on the [download page](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

Comment: You don't have to mess around with the `tool` folder. Just `./configure && make sqldiff`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using this tool: http://download.cnet.com/SQLite-Diff/3000-10254_4-10894771.html ?
But you can use the solution provided by @indienick provided you first dump the binary sqlite database with something like: sqlite x.db .dump > output.sql

Hope this helps,
Moszi

Comment: How exactly do I dump my SQLite? I do not have a sqlite command line installed.

Comment: If you use a standard Mac box, then you should have sqlite in /usr/bin/sqlite3 ;)

Comment: The last time I checked, you did not need to worry about dumping SQLite files, as SQLite works directly with a .sql file - it's not all hidden away in binary flat-files, like PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: Got it, and it works. Now I have to decide who gets the V - @indienick got it 90% right, but you brought it home... :)

Comment: hahh :) - thats all right :) award it to indienick, his answer was faster then mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a free web tool to compare SQLite databases, both schema and data -
https://ksdbmerge.tools/for-sqlite-online
Works on wasm-compatible browsers including Safari on Mac.

I am the author of that tool, it is an uno-platform port of my desktop tool for SQLite.
Unlike few other online tools I could find - it does not upload your data to the server to generate data diff. However it uploads schema to handle the rest of logic.

As of June 2022 it is diff-only tool, web version does not produce any syncronization scripts.