# Test for changes in sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, diff

I have an application that works with an sqlite database. I'd like to run this application, make some operation in the application (e.g. click a button) and then see what has changed in the database. I'd like to see everything that changed ofter this operation.

Is it possible in sqlite to save a state somehow and after a few minutes view the differences (old state versus new state)?

thank you

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580368/how-can-i-diff-2-sqlite-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: [snapshot reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12095_01/doc.10303/e16214/smanage.htm#CACEBCJE)

maybe a bit easier, depending on size: you could export to csv, make some changes, export again, compare csv's